# Laravel 5 Undefined variable: user / Include Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get this Error Message with this Code:

Error Message:

```
Undefined variable: user
```

Code:

```
@if($user->VIP == true)<span class="label label-VIP">VIP</span>@endif</span>
```

I think i must include to my blade the ProfileController or how can i do it?

This code works in the User Profile.

Thanks

Comment: update the your blade,controller, route code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call a view you need to specificate your parameter

in you controlloer class

```
public function MyFunction(Request $request){
   $myData = "Hello!"
   view('myview',['Text' => $myData ]);
}
```

or in you routefile

```
Route::get('/HelloPage', function () {
    $myData = "Hello!"
    view('myview',['Text' => $myData ]);
}
```

or with utl paramiter

```
Route::get('/HelloPage/{Text}', function ($Text) {
    view('myview',['Text' => $Text]);
}
```

on your .blade.php file you have to write

```
echo $Text;
```

Comment: in your controller

Comment: if you give me a second rewrite the answer specifying better

Comment: Thanks, i am beginner

Answer (score 0):

not very much clear but you can do something like this in you controller

```
public function your_function(){
$user = [
"VIP" => true,
]
 return view(your_blade_view)->with('user',$user);
}
```

just enter your view name without ".blade.php" extension

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a specific parameter with your view file or blade file from a controller.

for example.

```
public function index(){
  $name = 'foo bar';
  return view('index')->withName($name);
}
```

Print in blade file

```
{{ $name }}
```

OR

```
public function index(){
  $data = 'Hello world';
  return \View::make('index')->with('data',  $data);
}
```

Print in blade file

```
{{ $data }}
```

OR

```
public function index(){
  return view('index')->with('data', 'hello world');
}
```

Print in blade file

```
{{ $data }}
```

OR

```
public function index(){
  return view('index')
        ->with('first_name', 'foo')
        ->with('last_name', 'bar');

}
```

Print in blade file

```
{{ $first_name }}
{{ $last_name }}
```

OR

```
public function index(){
    $first_name = 'foo';
    $last_name = 'bar';
    return view('index', compact('first_name', 'last_name'));
}
```

Print in blade file

```
{{ $first_name }} 
{{ $last_name }}
```

OR

```
public function index(){
  return view('index', [
    'data' => ['hello', 'world', 'welcome']
 ]);
}
```

Print in blade file

```
print_r($data);
```

OR

```
public function index(){
  $data = [
        'first_name' => 'foo',
        'last_name' => 'bar'
    ];
    return view('index', compact('data'));
}
```

Print in blade file

```
print_r($data); 
{{ $data['first_name'] }}
```